# Creating an Upload Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm pretty sure there's a simple answer to a couple questions I have, but can't seem to figure it out on my own.

Basically I want to have a link where people (even without logging in to gmail) can upload files to my google drive. I have a script running right now that had a text box and an upload and submit button, but I need it to do a few more things.

The tutorial I followed: here:http://www.labnol.org/internet/receive-files-in-google-drive/19697/

So I have that script running, but right now it's not as complicated as I hope. I would like to have a form that has text boxes "File Name" that renames the uploaded file to what is typed in.

For example, if someone types in "photo of dog" in the File Name box and uploads photo.jpg I want it to upload "Photo_Of_Dog.jpg" in to my google drive. Basically just renaming the file to whatever text is typed (with space notations).

Please let me know if there's any information I have not provided.

Thanks in advanced!
J

Answer (score 1):

On the server side Google Script, add a line after the file is saved.

```
var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
file.rename(file.getName().replace(" ", "_"));
```